# LaTex error- !Paragraph ended before \split was complete

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am using `amsmath` package but keep getting errors with the following:

```
\begin{split}
\[
A_R&=\frac{4}{9}+\frac{20}{81}+\frac{100}{729}+\frac{500}{6561}+\dots \\
&=\frac{4}{3^2}+5\times\frac{4}{3^4}+5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^6}+5\times5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^8}+\dots \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^{2n}} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^2n+2}} \\
&=\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{5}{9}} \\ 
&=1
\]
\end{split}
```

The error is detected on the line after `\end{split}` and I cannot understand why.
I also get:

```
! Argument of \split has an extra }.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

Comment: Wrong nesting order and spurious closing brace at the end of line 4. It should be `\[
\begin{split}
A_R&=\frac{4}{9}+\frac{20}{81}+\frac{100}{729}+\frac{500}{6561}+\dots \\
&=\frac{4}{3^2}+5\times\frac{4}{3^4}+5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^6}+5\times5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^8}+\dots \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^{2n}} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^2n+2} \\
&=\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{5}{9}} \\ 
&=1
\end{split}
\]`

Comment: Why don't you use `align*` instead?

Comment: Thank you! I have used yours and changed split to aligned and it is now working :) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

The very last `}` of the line `&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^2n+2}} \\` shouldn't be there. Plus, the `split` environment must be placed *inside* math mode, not outside:

```
\[
\begin{split}
A_R&=\frac{4}{9}+\frac{20}{81}+\frac{100}{729}+\frac{500}{6561}+\dots \\
&=\frac{4}{3^2}+5\times\frac{4}{3^4}+5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^6}+5\times5\times5\times\frac{4}{3^8}+\dots \\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^{2n}} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}5^{n-1}\times\frac{4}{3^2n+2}} \\
&=\frac{\frac{4}{9}}{1-\frac{5}{9}} \\ 
&=1
\end{split}
\]
```